# Como passar um array de dados para uma view laravel?

Tags: laravel

Como eu passo um resultado de um select para uma view?

```
public function index()
{
    $equipams = DB::table('equipamentos')
            ->select('equipamentos.*', 'tipoequipamentos.descricaotipoequip', 'locals.descricaolocal',
                     'tipoequipamentos.descricaotipoequip', 'fabricantes.descricaofabricante',
                     'fornecedors.descricaofornecedor')
            ->join('tipoequipamentos', 'tipoequipamentos.id','=', 'equipamentos.idtipoequipamento')
            ->join('fabricantes', 'fabricantes.id','=', 'equipamentos.idfabr')
            ->join('fornecedors', 'fornecedors.id','=', 'equipamentos.idforn')
            ->join('locals', 'locals.id','=', 'equipamentos.idloca')
            ->get();

    //dd($equipam);
    //$equipamentos = \App\Models\Portal\Equipamento::paginate(3);
    return view('portal.equipamento.index', 'equipam');
}
```

Comment: Na view:            @forelse ($equipams as equipam)
Data erro: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Comment: Não seria `@foreach($equipams as $equipam)`?

Answer (score 1):

Assim

```
return view('portal.equipamento.index', compact('equipams'));
```

Ou assim:

```
return view('portal.equipamento.index', ['equipams'=>$equipams]);
```

Não view pode referenciar assim `$equipams`.

Recomendo ler a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views) ou um tutorial, pois essa é uma pergunta bem básica.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Uma coisa que acho engraçado que a função links() não funciona com arrays de selects? Só com tablelas?

Comment: Se eu passo como array dá erro. Se eu passo como objeto dá outro erro:
Call to undefined method stdClass::links()

Comment: Isso por que você está utilizando `->get()`, em vez disso deve utilizar `->paginate(15)`, para páginas de 15 elementos por exemplo. Mais detalhes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination. Ah, e não esqueça de marcar está resposta com correta, já que resolveu teu problema.